# Coinflips by using multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

I am writting a program: 'flip coin by using threads'. Each threads are fliping coin, if flipped head thread stop, if flipped tail, thread should flip until you get head and then stop thsi thread, at the end each thread counts how many tails i fliped in row an printf this as a number.

This is what i ve done :

```
        import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

/**
 *
 * @author jakub ozorowski
 */
final class RzutMoneta {
 public static Float p;

  public static void main(String... argv) {


    System.out.print("Ilość wątków: ");
    int ilość;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);  
    ilość = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Prawdopodobieństwo reszki: ");
    p = in.nextFloat();

    ExecutorService watki = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
    for (int i = 0; i < ilość; ++i)
      watki.submit(RzutMoneta::run); // wyskakuje w eclipse java problem????? w netbeansie działa bez problemu
    watki.shutdown();
  }

  private static void run() {
    Moneta moneta = new Moneta();
    int count = 0;
    while (moneta.rzut() == Moneta.Strony.Reszka) {
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": reszka!");
      ++count;
    }
    System.out.printf("%s: orzel! %d reszka%n", Thread.currentThread().getName(), count);
  }

}

final class  Moneta {
   public static double p;

    Moneta() {
        Moneta.p = RzutMoneta.p;
    }

  enum Strony {
    Orzeł, Reszka
  }

  Strony rzut() {

    //return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextBoolean() ? Strony.Orzeł : Strony.Reszka;
    return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextFloat() > p ? Strony.Orzeł : Strony.Reszka;  
  }

}

my output:

    Number of threads: 3
tails chance: 0,5
pool-1-thread-2: heads! 0 tails
pool-1-thread-3: tails!
pool-1-thread-1: heads! 0 tails
pool-1-thread-3: tails!
pool-1-thread-3: tails!
pool-1-thread-3: heads! 3 tails
```

//edit working program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, one obstacle you'll face is that all of your threads are using a single object to track coin flips (the `Rzut_Moneta` instance `test`), but you want each thread to print the number of tails flipped. How do you segregate the results of one thread from the others? It seems like each thread should maintain its own counter.

In order to keep flipping on a tails, you need a loop. Something like this:

```
while (flip() == Reszka) {
  ++count;
  System.out.println("Tails! Flip again.");
}
System.out.println("Heads!");
```

It looks like you are having trouble with variable scope as well. You have declared all of your variables as fields in the object, but most of these should be local variables, inside the method. I don't see a need for any fields.

If you needed to share data between threads, your `Rzut_Moneta` class isn't safe; it has no memory barriers, so there's no guarantee that changes by each thread would be visible. For example, if you wanted to count the total number of tails seen by all threads, that counter would need to be declared as `volatile`, or be accessed only in `synchronized` blocks, or be of a special type like [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html).

If each thread has its own private counter, there's no need to worry about these concurrency issues.

I'd suggest a structure like this (just a sketch, you'll have to fill in details from your original code):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

final class RzutMoneta {

  public static void main(String... argv) {
    int ilość;
    double headProbability;
    try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
      System.out.print("Number of threads: ");
      ilość = input.nextInt();
      System.out.print("Chance of heads: ");
      headProbability = input.nextDouble();
    }
    ExecutorService threads = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
    for (int i = 0; i < ilość; ++i)
      threads.submit(() -> run(headProbability));
    threads.shutdown();
  }

  private static void run(double headProbability) {
    Moneta moneta = new Moneta(headProbability);
    int count = 0;
    while (moneta.rzut() == Moneta.Stroną.Reszka) {
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": tails!");
      ++count;
    }
    System.out.printf("%s: heads! %d tails%n", Thread.currentThread().getName(), count);
  }

}

final class Moneta {

  enum Stroną {
    Orzeł, Reszka
  }

  private final double headProbability;

  Moneta() {
    this(0.5);
  }

  Moneta(double headProbability) {
    if ((headProbability < 0) || (headProbability > 1))
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Probability between 0.0 and 1.0");
    this.headProbability = headProbability;
  }

  Stroną rzut() {
    double toss = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble();
    return (toss < headProbability) ? Stroną.Orzeł : Stroną.Reszka;
  }

}
```

Comment: Can u put together ur code with my main ? i do not know where to paste this.

Comment: @JaKoZo Okay, I added a complete program.

Comment: So,seems legit :D. Can u show me in code where is probability of getting tails ? Because i want to change this probability for example to 0,2..

Comment: You'd need to replace the call to `nextBoolean()` with something else. Perhaps something like `ThreadLocalRandom.nextDouble() < 0.2 ? ...`

Comment: Yes i was trying this but then i get error(non-static method nextDouble() cannot be referenced from a static context)

Comment: Sorry that should be `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65228/discussion-between-jakozo-and-erickson).

Comment: my last question to this program is : 
if i want to dynamically changing tails probability from my keyboard when i start program i mean. i Should 
return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble() < probability ? Strony.Orzeł : Strony.Reszka; how to add this to "probability " to scanner from this fuction rzut()..

Comment: @JaKoZo I added that capability to the program.

Comment: @JaKoZo Sorry, I forgot to hit save before leaving yesterday.

Comment: Check my 1st post i paste my solution. i think my does the same as urs.

Comment: It looks pretty good. It should give the same results. I would suggest taking away the `static` modifier on the variable `p` in `Moneta` object. An instance should not modify members of its class.